# React useState good practice

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I've created an alert box. Whenever the user clicks the button, an alert based upon operation (success or fail) will popup.

The problem is sometimes it displays old state (i.e., prev values) when button is clicked and takes a sec to display the updated message. Also, my question is - Is there a better/proper way to achieve this?

````
const AccountSettings = () => {

    const { user, userData, updateEmailAddress, verifyEmail } = UserAuth()

    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [alertBox, setAlertBox] = useState(false);
    const [alertName, setalertName] = useState('');
    const [alertMessage, setalertMessage] = useState('');
    const [alertType, setalertType] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setAlertBox(false)
            setalertName("")
            setalertMessage("")
            setalertType("")
        }, 5000);
    }, [alertBox])

    const handleChange = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setAlertBox(true)
        try {
            await updateEmailAddress(email);
            setalertName("Success")
            setalertMessage(`Your email has been updated to ${email}`)
            setalertType("success")
        } catch (e) {
            setalertName("Error Occured")
            setalertMessage(e.message)
            setalertType("fail")
            console.log(e.message);
        }
    };

    const handleVerify = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setAlertBox(true)
        try {
            await verifyEmail();
            setalertName("Verification mail sent")
            setalertMessage("Check your mail to confirm your account")
            setalertType("success")
            console.log("sent");
        } catch (e) {
            setalertName("Error Occured")
            setalertMessage(e.message)
            setalertType("fail")
            console.log(e.message)
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            {user ?
                <div className="flex flex-col gap-5 w-full">

                    {alertBox === true ?
                        <MessageAlert name={alertName} message={alertMessage} type={alertType} />
                        :
                        <></>
                    }
                </div>
              }
            </>
           )
} ```
````

Comment: I'd say the fact that you're setting a lot of state at the same time looks like a code smell to me. I think using only one object state or maybe even a useReducer would be much better

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask].

Comment: The problem is also that you're setting alertBox as soon as you do the change but the update seems to take a bit more time so you display the alert box with some outdated state